# AngularJS + RequireJS [ Error Injection ]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

## Introduction

I development a struct using AngularJS and RequireJS. I started REquireJS in little time ago and show difficulties in implement AngularJS in RequireJS.

### Problem

My problem it is in dependencies in `app/assets/js/app.js:4` :

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=opaApp&p1=Error%3A%….0.1%3A57966%2Fapp%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A219)

#### Conclusion

If you have any tips for improvement, please share them.

#### Code - update

[github](https://github.com/ralfting/angular-require)

Comment: Well short answer is your are not setting up the require modules correctly (it's looking for a module that it can't find mostly likely because it is not injected correctly) , would have to see the code and setup you have for requirejs and angular though. Maybe set up one example in a plunkr or drop it in here or something?

Comment: @ajmajmajma sorry, I forget xD. Add Code above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Manually bootstrap your application after defining the app module, instead of using the ng-app directive.

So, remove ng-app="opaApp" from the html tag in index.html and add

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['opaApp']);
```

after angular.module('opaApp', ['opaApp.application']); in app.js

The reason you are getting the error is because angular tries to start the application (looking at the ng-app directive) before the opaApp module is defined.